# Pandas seting column in new dataframe replace old dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I wish to update column in one based on the another. The problem is that when I update the column, the old dataframe gets rewritten as well.

(One dataframe contains correlation between column and target variable, the other is supposed to show the ranking)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:100]
y = iris.target[:100]
clmns = iris.feature_names

out = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,len(clmns)), columns=['coef'])

feat_coef = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Feature_name','pearson_koef_FM']) 

feat_coef['Feature_name'] = clmns
feat_rank = feat_coef

X_np = np.array(X)
y_np = np.array(y)
for idx,name in enumerate(clmns):
    out['coef'].loc[idx] = pearsonr(X_np[:,idx], y_np)[0]

feat_coef['pearson_koef_FM'] = np.absolute(out['coef'])

print '----BEFORE----'      
print feat_coef

feat_rank['pearson_koef_FM'] = feat_coef['pearson_koef_FM'].rank(ascending=False)

print '----AFTER----'     
print feat_coef
```

Which returns this:

```
----BEFORE----
        Feature_name pearson_koef_FM
0  sepal length (cm)         0.72829
1   sepal width (cm)        0.684019
2  petal length (cm)        0.969955
3   petal width (cm)        0.960158
----AFTER----
        Feature_name  pearson_koef_FM
0  sepal length (cm)              3.0
1   sepal width (cm)              4.0
2  petal length (cm)              1.0
3   petal width (cm)              2.0
```

Obviously, I expect the `feat_coef` remain unchanged. If I print `feat_rank`, I get correct output. I feel like it has something to do with setting a copy vs view when copying dataframes.

Comment: `feat_rank` is a __reference__, so replace `feat_rank = feat_coef` with `feat_rank = feat_coef.copy()`

Comment: I knew it will be something like this. Works perfectly! Could you explain why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line:

```
feat_rank = feat_coef
```

`feat_rank` is a reference to `feat_coef`:

```
In [9]: feat_rank is feat_coef
Out[9]: True

In [10]: id(feat_rank)
Out[10]: 177476664

In [11]: id(feat_coef)
Out[11]: 177476664

In [12]: id(feat_coef) == id(feat_rank)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: feat_rank['new'] = 100

In [14]: feat_coef
Out[14]:
        Feature_name pearson_koef_FM  new
0  sepal length (cm)         0.72829  100
1   sepal width (cm)        0.684019  100
2  petal length (cm)        0.969955  100
3   petal width (cm)        0.960158  100
```

So if you change any existing column (value) in the reference DF `feat_rank` - it will be done on the source DF `feat_coef`

**Solution:** if you need an independent DF use `.copy()`:

```
feat_rank = feat_coef.copy()
```